# using fdfgen forge_fdf, how to fill arabic text in pdf form

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-form

I am not able to write Arabic text in pdf form though forge_fdf function in python
while Arabic text is working with

```
reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
```

but canvas is not supporting to fill pdf form.

See my code

```
pdf_file = currentpath+ "test1.pdf"
tmp_file = currentpath+ "data.pdf"
output_file  = currentpath+ "output.pdf"

name = u'Ahmad said "السلام عليكم" (as-salaam alaykum] to me.'
fields = [('name', name), ('email', 'a السلام عليكم a'), ('phone', 'a السلام عليكم a'), ('rd','female'),('chk','Yes'),('chk2','Yes')]

fdf = forge_fdf("", fields, [], [], [])
fdf_file = open(tmp_file,"w")

fdf_file.write(fdf)
fdf_file.close()

cmd = 'pdftk "{0}" fill_form "{1}" output "{2}"  flatten'.format(pdf_file, tmp_file, output_file);
os.system(cmd)
```

when I run this code pdf form filled but Arabic text does not showing and all english is showing correctly.

I am using encoding also but not getting success

Can any one has done this...........